# Library Message Handling

Tags: c#

I am building a library which can parse complex files into a datamodel. Inside the library during parsing and during some other operations on the data structure I am building certain messages might occur (info, warnings, errors).

I need a way for the user of the library to fetch those messages. All stuff I am thinking about boils down to some static Event or a static list of those messages. But I want each object of the datastructure to have its own message queue.

An example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CalibData cd1 = new CalibData();
        cd1.LoadFile(@"C:\tmp\file.ext");
        var messageList = cd1.GetMessages();
        cd1.DoOtherStuff();


        CalibData cd2 = new CalibData();
        cd2.LoadFile(@"C:\tmp\file2.ext");
        cd2.LoadFile(@"C:\tmp\file3.ext2");

        messageList = cd1.GetMessages(); //Do other stuff could have produced new Messages
        var messageList2 = cd2.GetMessages();

    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to implement such behavoir? I need something which is globally accessibly inside each instance, but each instance has another global messenger.

Additional Information:
Internall I am using an ANTLR Parser which generates a lot of objects (50.000+). Once the datastructure is created a lot of crossreferences are being set on the objects, etc. My main problem is, that I either have to create a static member to handle this, or from LoadFile() pass a messenger very deep into my function calls of the parser, cross referencing etc. In my opionion both is a rather bad choice. Changing the design is not an option since there is more to my problem. The datastructure is stored in 2 files (1 file = description, other file = data). So I can call something like

```
CalibData cd = new CalibData();
cd.LoadFile("description file"); //after this call the datastructure is built, but it hasn't got any value data yet
cd.LoadFile("data file") //now the structure also has value data
cd.ClearData();
cd.LoadFile("yet another data file"); //same structure different data
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `LoadFile` method currently doesn't return anything - why not make it return a data structure containing the errors, warnings etc? No need for anything global or static - or even persistent. Just the result of a method call.

In fact, I'd *probably* change this slightly so that a separate class (rather than the model itself) was responsible for loading, and the `LoadFile` call would return a result containing:

- Information and errors
- The resulting model object

That way any time you have a model you know it contains actual data - rather than it being "ready to load" as it were.

Comment: I thought about that, but the model is more complex. It can hold more than one model (for each filetype one model). I know the design could be changed all together, but the users demand it that way, most of them are engineers not software developers. LoadFile actually generated stuff internally in the CalibData object instead of returning something.

Comment: @metacircle: It seems to me that there's more context here than you've told us, making it impossible to really answer satisfactorily. Yes, I understand that `LoadFile` generates things internally in `CalibData` - I'm saying that's a bad design, but *even if* you want to keep with that design, you can use the return value of `LoadFile` to indicate the errors and warnings.

Comment: @metacircle: Not really. This feels like the kind of question where any suggestion that's made is going to be rejected due to another bit of information we didn't have. In the original question you seemed to be asking about the API - but now your question complains that it would be too hard to collect the messages within the *implementation*. Any time you ask a design question but state (after the fact) that the design can't be changed, it's going to be hard to satisfy you.